# How to keep a computer updated?

Tags: windows, drivers, firmware

What the best way to keep a computer updated when it comes to drivers and firmwares etc? I currently have to remember to visit Intel and other companies that have components installed on my machine ... Are there any application that scan my machine and check ALL for all new version for ALL vendors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used Device Doctor for a while now, and it seems pretty good at finding driver updates. No ads, and is pretty straightforward.